# issue with console log for google apps scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to troubleshoot the below code (the main problem is that I can't get the range to display) and I've included a log command to show what is being printed out. When I run doGet() and go to View > Logs it says: "[16-10-07 17:31:19:145 EDT] number for you: Range"

sheet.getRange("H1:DE1") refers to part of a row that has dates.  Shouldn't it list the contents of the row?

```
function doGet() { 

// The code below opens a spreadsheet using its id and logs the name for it.
// Note that the spreadsheet is NOT physically opened on the client side.
// It is opened on the server only (for modification by the script).
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aCXXXXXXXXXXXXw61H6VuigRf6YykW8O6A0WWmG46VO7ijI/edit#gid=1673918325');
```

Logger.log(ss.getName());

```
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
var range = sheet.getRange("H1:DE1");
Logger.log('number for you: %s', range);

// Calling this method with "true" sets the first line to be the title of the axes
var datatable = range.getDataTable(true);

// Note that this doesn't build an EmbeddedChart, so we can't just use
// Sheet#insertChart(). If we want to do that, we should use
// sheet.newChart().addRange() instead.
var chart = Charts.newBarChart()
.setDataTable(datatable)
.setOption("title", "Your Title Here")
.build();

var app = UiApp.createApplication();
app.add(chart);
ss.show(app);


}
```

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1):

You can't to print the range object in this way. Instead you have to write `range.getRow()` or `range.getColumn()`. Please note you  have various get functions of the `range` object.

Answer (score 0):

The range object does not contain sheet values. In order to get them use either of the following:

```
values = range.getValues();  // gets internal values
values = range.getDisplayValues();  // gets displayed values
```

The best approach to fix errors in an apps script is to use the built in debugger (not the Logger object, not the execution transcript) and breakpoints, like this:

1. At the script editors top bar, find the dropdown menu and select a function you want to debug
2. Set a breakpoint: click the index of a line you would like to pause at (assume to be buggy)
3. Click the bug icon in the top bar to run the script in debug mode up to the specified breakpoint
4. Inspect your variables in the opened tab
5. Step through the lines of your script line by line by clicking the step in, step out, and step over buttons (at the right of the script editors top bar)